# The method 'add' was called on null while getting image from image picker

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am getting the image by image picker and then adding the file to the list of file but it shows the error-**The method 'add' was called on null.**.
My code:-

```
final picker=ImagePicker();    
selectImageFromGallery() async
      {
        setState(() {
          inProcess=true;
        });
        final imageFile= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        if(imageFile!=null)
          {
            File _image=File(imageFile.path);
            files.add(_image);
          }
        setState(() {
          inProcess=false;
        });
      }
```

Comment: where are you defining `files`?

Comment: Am defining it in my statefull widget. as List<File> files;

Comment: I added an answer that should fix it for you.

Comment: If you're programming you should atleast know that you should instantiate your variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like files is a `List<File>` but it's not properly initialized.

You need to initialize it as an empty list, such as:

```dart
final files = <File>[];
```

so you can add files to it.

Comment: oh man, thanks i was doing such a dumb mistake

Comment: @DeepakLohmod no problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.